# Jetpack Compose not changing background color to the white

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm learning android jetpack compose and noticed a weird behaviour in the app. If I set **light theme** background colour to **white**. And I set the dark theme variable to false, also I switch my **system colour mode to Dark**. Then it will **not show white colour**.

I have tried every possible method. If I place a colour other then white then it will work Like a charm.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JetPackComposeDeepDiveTheme(
                 false, {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}
```

In color.kt I have added These two colours. The rest Whole project is a starter project.

```
val DarkBackground = Color(0xFF000000)
val LightBackground = Color(0XFFFFFFFF)
```

And I'm consuming these colors in theme.kt

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Purple200,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200,
    background = DarkBackground,
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Purple500,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200,
    background = LightBackground,
)

@Composable
fun JetPackComposeDeepDiveTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

I have no idea if is this a bug or if I'm doing something wrong. If I'm doing it the right way then please correct me. If it's an android bug then where I can report this?

Answer (score 0):

Some devices use force dark mode. Like Xiaomi devices. I have POCO f1, it has force dark mode already enabled. So, it would be best if you disabled that. Then your application will give you the desired output.